# Patient with pain in upper ear area

Tags: ear

We have one case with pain in the upper part of left ear and on left side of the neck, also a sense of muscle pain in left side of his body, after being in the front of fan for one night; the pain position is shown below:

[image]

So i guess it could be **occipital neuralgia**, but the pain is not sharp and there is an edema an redness on the upper side of his ear. The Ear canal also has some edema; the patient also suffers from some stress. He has got **Naproxen 500** for every 12 hr for two days.

I like to know what cusses this pain? Could it be from stress?

Thanks.

Comment: He needs to see a doctor. We cannot diagnose individual cases here.

Comment: @DoctorWhom, it appears to me it may be a doctor who asked the question. So, maybe, it could be appropriate to suggest a differential diagnosis.

Comment: @Jan The potential differential is way too serious to discuss here and requires an exam, and the manner this is presented is not consistent with how a physician/NP/PA would usually approach it so I have my doubts.  But regardless, there is no clear syndrome that would encompass this constellation of symptoms and a thorough history/exam is paramount due to the redness/edema.  Otitis externa can become malignant, temporal arteritis can be fatal, the neck is already involved, and it's already been two days.  I would not wait and I'd seek medical attention.